# Google+ and OpenGraph

Tags: google-plus, share, facebook-opengraph

Testing url: https://newton.ai/newton/opp/indeed/2345baacb4ce1b34

When sharing on Facebook I'm able to get the right information from the page, but the same doesn't happen when I try to share on Google+.

On Google+ it selects a wrong image from the page, the title from the title element and a piece of debug code that I've no idea of where it comes from:

```
Code Context (int) 1, 'jobs' => array( 'results' => array( (int) 0 => array( [maximum depth reached] ) ) ...
```

The metatags have this structure:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="We have more than 1000000 of offers waiting for you :)">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Newton.ai">
<meta property="og:description" content="Medical S.A is hiring Nurse m/f">
<meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:image" content="https://newton.ai/img/newton/newton_azul.png">
```

I tried to get the page using curl with the UserAgent of "Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)" and there's no error in the file.

And when testing using https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ the result is:

- pmr-cse_image
- pmr-cse_image-src
- pmr-metatags-og_description
- pmr-metatags-og_description-a
- pmr-metatags-og_description-f
- pmr-metatags-og_description-hiring
- pmr-metatags-og_description-is
- pmr-metatags-og_description-m
- pmr-metatags-og_description-medical
- pmr-metatags-og_description-nurse
- pmr-metatags-og_description-s
- pmr-metatags-og_image
- pmr-metatags-og_site_name
- pmr-metatags-og_site_name-ai
- pmr-metatags-og_site_name-newton
- pmr-metatags-og_site_name-newton.ai
- pmr-metatags-og_title
- pmr-metatags-og_title-1000000
- pmr-metatags-og_title-for
- pmr-metatags-og_title-have
- pmr-metatags-og_title-more
- pmr-metatags-og_title-of
- pmr-metatags-og_title-offers
- pmr-metatags-og_title-than
- pmr-metatags-og_title-waiting
- pmr-metatags-og_title-we
- pmr-metatags-og_title-you
- pmr-metatags-og_type
- pmr-metatags-og_type-article
- pmr-metatags-viewport
- pmr-metatags-viewport-1
- pmr-metatags-viewport-device
- pmr-metatags-viewport-device-width
- pmr-metatags-viewport-initial
- pmr-metatags-viewport-initial-scale
- pmr-metatags-viewport-scale
- pmr-metatags-viewport-width

Comment: The server is taking to long to respond so Google+ isn't populating any details now. Also the response is trying to set a cookie a [huge number of times](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2AOTS.png).

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me which command did you run?

Comment: `curl -v https://newton.ai/newton/opp/indeed/2345baacb4ce1b34 > /dev/null`